# Logging messages from one channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, channel

I've tried several times to work this and I don't understand the error, I am receiving but I'll explain what I'm trying to do: Basically I want to log the messages from one channel and paste those messages onto a different channel. Here is the code I have so far;

```
client.on(`message`, message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // If the message is by a bot return.
    if (!message.guild) return; // If the message isn't in a guild return.
    if (message.guild) {
        const msgLog = `[MESSAGE] [${message.guild.name}] [#${message.channel.name}] ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}: ${message.content}\n` // You can change this to whatever you want.
        client.channels.get(`814685640088223795`).send(msgLog); // Replace CHANNEL ID with the channel ID you want the logs to go to.
        return;
    }
})
```

The error I am receiving goes as follows:

```
(node:17260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\stuff\S1 Discord Bot\s1-bot\src\events\message\message.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at registerEvents (D:\stuff\S1 Discord Bot\s1-bot\src\utils\registry.js:33:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17260) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this from your index file:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
//under const Discord etc
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

If you are trying to only allow guildMessages, you do it like this:

```js
if (message.channel.type === "dm") return; //dont react to dms
```

Finally, to send a message to a channel by id:

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.get('814685640088223795').send(msglog); //using 'cache' since v12 uses managers
```

Comment: I added that but now it gives me this error 

(node:8640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Discord is not defined

Comment: look at my edit, you seem to be missing the Discord definition also

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner to coding with Discord.js and using node but I've incorporated what you said and this is my code thus far: https://www.codepile.net/pile/WKBVdwKP

I am also receiving another error but that could be because I've entered the code wrong but here's my error: 

(node:2552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at MessageEvent.run (D:\stuff\S1 Discord Bot\s1-bot\src\events\MessageEvent.js:9:30

Comment: `tag` is not in your code attached and so I cannot debug your error, it seems you are trying to run before you can walk here - as you seem to be attempting the use of a handler (I'm not sure what `MessageEvent.js` is). To start, I would highly recommend using 1 `index.js` file for all of your commands. Add my Discord in my profile if you need more help, if you believe the above is the correct answer for your question above, please mark it as correct. You also took no notice of my changes to your code above, I would recommend adding those in to save future errors.

Comment: Ok, I'll add your discord.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing two important lines of code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Appending these two lines from the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) documentation in the beginning of your index.js file should make it work.

Comment: I have a feeling he is missing far more than just those lines